# MapboxOptimizedTrips missing from package MapboxSDK.AndroidServices (Xamarin.Android)

Tags: xamarin.android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I'm currently implementing MapBox in a `Xamarin.Android` application, I'm looking at the examples from MapBox Github, this one in specific https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/blob/master/MapboxAndroidDemo/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxandroiddemo/examples/mas/OptimizationActivity.java, which I'm translating to C#, but now I'm facing a problem. In this example they use a class called "MapboxOptimizedTrips" which comes from lib 'com.mapbox.services.api.optimizedtrips.v1.MapboxOptimizedTrips'. In Xamarin I have imported all libraries that Xamarin made for MapBox, which is these 3:

- `MapBoxSDK.Android`
- `MapBoxSDK.AndroidServices`
- `MapBoxSDK.JavaServices`

None of these includes the Optimized Trips API related classes. Has anyone faced this issue before?

[Screenshot of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTRfb.png)

Comment: For anyone who wonders about this issue, I made my way around this by calling the API manually like this https://api.mapbox.com/optimized-trips/v1/mapbox/driving/-122.42,37.78;-122.45,37.91;-122.48,37.73?access_token=your-access-token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought you read and followed [this document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48401451/mapboxoptimizedtrips-missing-from-package-mapboxsdk-androidservices-xamarin-and) from Mapbox?

1. Mapbox Navigation library is kept changing and adding new features
2. There are two DirectionsRoute class from Mapbox libraries
3. both DirectionsRoute returned by Mapbox Optimization packages doesn't fit with what NavigationRoute does.

I think you have to go with the way you mentioned, call to API directly. Or wait for Mapbox to evolve their library.

Cheers.